# WSDL xs:element name and type are same

Tags: cxf

Here is the part of WSDL, i am generating WSDL from java code using javxs and spring.

```
    <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://service.try.test/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://service.try.test/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="testMail" type="tns:testMail"/>
<xs:complexType name="testMail">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="file" type="tns:mailTestsersList"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

In below line name and type are matching. I need to give different type name.

```
<xs:element name="testMail" type="tns:testMail"/>
```

How can i do this? where i need to make changes to reflect changes in WSDl?